# Cannot update plugin

Tags: plugin-development, updates, automatic-updates

I've implemented [this](https://pastebin.com/J442ATVB) class for update my plugin, I've followed [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-license-controlled-update-system-doing-the-update--cms-22675) tutorial.

I tested the update in localhost using XAMPP and everything works well, but unfortunately when I test on a live site I get a weird situation that doesn't allow me to update the plugin.

Essentially, I can see the update notification in the panel, when I update the plugin seems that everything was done correctly but for some reason in the `plugins` folder I get this:

[image]

As you can see the plugin folder has been replaced with a temporary one, within `get-IO5hpY` there are the updated plugins file. So here the question:

Why wordpress replace my plugin folder name which is `my-plugin` with `get-IO5HpY`?

Comment: Have you raised this with the authors of that class? The tutorial you're following is using code from https://github.com/jarkkolaine/wp-license-manager-client which is 7/8 years old now, it may not be the best solution for creating a license system and you can raise issues on that github with the author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'uploaded-plugin'.zip must contain all your plugin files in subdirectory named as your plugin subdirectory (in example "my-plugin").